# VS2015 Changes my files whenever I open them

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm not sure what setting has changed or what is going on here, but whenever I open a file in Visual Studio Community 2015 it shows pending changes immediately.

Does anyone know what is going on here?  It's really getting annoying and keeps messing up my version control with all these changed files that haven't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Dammit.  Just found my answer.  It's actually a plugin called PHP Tools that I use.  It's changing the Line Endings to Unix LF on open.  Changed it to "Keep Current Settings" and it's not doing it now.

Mystery solved.